# Netflix style next episode for Exoplayer Leanback

Tags: android, android-layout, exoplayer, leanback

I am working on an Android TV Application using leanback library. I was able to integrate VideoPlaybackActivty using Exoplayer. One of my requirement is when there is about 1 minute left for current video to end, I need to make a Rest call to the server to fetch next video to play and than I would like to show the Next Video thumbnail at the bottom right of the screen. Very much similar to the Netflix functionality of "Next Episode playing in....".

My questions is, how can I find out if there is just 1 minute left in the video. Also, how can I show that "Play Next overlay" on the screen? Currently my activity_videoplayback.xml look as follows.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextureView
        android:id="@+id/texture_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/playback_controls_fragment"
        android:name="com.myapp.ui.playback.VideoPlaybackFragment"
        android:tag="@string/playback_tag"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/stream_progressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/orange"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</merge>
```

Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

ExoPlayer does not provide a progress update listener at the moment - the reason cited is that it would eat up too much CPU to keep raising progress events. See the discussion on the ExoPlayer issue tracker here and note that the issue is considered closed at this time (Feb 2021):

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/3980

The suggested approach is to build a handler to poll the player and query the current position using player.getCurrentPosition().

For completeness, in case you are also looking at HTML5 video, in a WebView for example, you can check the video length and then use the progress event to check for 1 second from the end - this is 'standard' HTML5 and javascript so should work with any framework using the HTML5 video element.

The code might look something like this:

```js
const yourVideo = document.querySelector('yourVideoID');

//Create the event handler
function handleProgressEvent(event) {
    //Check if video has reached last 10 seconds
    if (yourVideo.currentTime > (yourVideo.duration - 10.0)) {
    // DO your work to prepare the next video here
    
    }
}

// Add the event listener to your video
yourVideo.addEventListener('progress', handleProgressEvent);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Any idea how can I add the layout for a small rectangle Image (button) that will popup at the end showing the thumbnail of the next video?

Comment: ExoPlayer allows you customise the existing controls or add new ones: https://exoplayer.dev/ui-components.html